# getJSON subset from API to display on a web

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to scrape some data from an API and turn data into my own website.

The API get request: 
http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter

I tried to display all the "titles" from that api in my own website. But somehow it doesn't work. I am sure I have jquery installed. with the code snippet:     `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

But nothing shows up when I'm loading the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Relief Web</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON('http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter', function(reliefResult) {

                document.write(reliefResult.title);

            });

        });
    <script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no title in your result.

Comment: Your browser is not a black box. You need to do some basic debugging. The bare minimum is finding the browser console so you can actually see JavaScript errors. Please ask for further directions if you don't know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter', function(reliefResult) {

    reliefResult.data.forEach(function(record) {
      $('body').append('<div>' + record.fields.title + '</div>');

    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code will currnently show `undefined` as `title` is a property of the objects in the `data` array. You need to loop through that array and create the elements you need. Try this:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter', function(reliefResult) {
    $.each(reliefResult.data, function(_, data) {
        $('div').append('<p>' + data.fields.title + '</p>');
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

jQuery provides many ways of adding and amending the content of the DOM, as such you should avoid the use of `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go with properties and sub properties of that JSON object which you get from API response.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            $.getJSON('http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter', function(reliefResult) {
for( i in reliefResult.data){
                document.write(reliefResult.data[i].fields.title + "<br/>");
  }

            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Title does exist in the result but not at the top level. You need to go down the js object that is created to the proper title you want.

Below is the result:

> {
>   "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?preset=latest&filter[field]=status&filter",
>   "time":4,    "links":{
>         "self":{
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?offset=0&limit=10&preset=latest"
>         },
>         "next":{
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs?offset=10&limit=10&preset=latest"
>         }    },    "totalCount":2254,    "count":10,    "data":[
>         {
>            "id":"1696121",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1696121",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Mali - Mission d\u2019\u00e9valuation et de diagnostic (SAME/EHA) (H/F) - Goundam"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1696101",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1696101",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Emergency Response Officer - Protection"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1696026",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1696026",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Site Operations Assistant-National Contract"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695986",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695986",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Call For Proposals FUND FOR NON \u2013 STATE ACTORS"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695841",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695841",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Regional Campaigner \u2013 Tunis Regional Office"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695831",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695831",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Regional Content Manager (Eurasia and Russia Teams - London Office)"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695806",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695806",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Campaigner for OPT \u2013 East Jerusalem or Ramallah Regional Office"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695786",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695786",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Communications coordinator MENA region"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695776",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695776",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"Project Officer Lebanon (Access to Higher Education programme)"
>            }
>         },
>         {
>            "id":"1695741",
>            "score":1,
>            "href":"http://api.reliefweb.int/v1/jobs/1695741",
>            "fields":{
>               "title":"TECHNICAL ADVISOR, SOCIAL AND BEHAVIOR CHANGE COMMUNICATION"
>            }
>         }    ] }

For example

> reliefResult.data[0].fields.title

should return "

> Mali - Mission d\u2019\u00e9valuation et de diagnostic (SAME/EHA)
>   (H/F) - Goundam

"

Answer (score -1):

That's because `title` is nested deeper in your data structure. In order to get first title you need to `document.write(reliefResult.data[0].fields.title)`

In order to list all titles, you need to map them:

```
reliefResult.data.map(function(e) {
    document.write(e.fields.title);
})
```